What does "No camping 10-21" mean?
Near Halden (Norway), I saw a sign that said:

Camping forbudt


No camping


10-21
(10-21)
10-21


Taken literally, this would mean the camping ban only applies between 10 and 21, and spending the night is allowed, seven days per week (the times refer to weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays/holidays, respectively).  But camping by definition (?) involves an overnight stay, so I find this interpretation puzzling.  What exactly is prohibited here?  I can sit and linger but have to wait until 21 to erect a tent?  I can camp by night, including multiple nights, as long as I remove my tent during the day?  Is it code for "tourists can spend the night, but no <insert unwanted nomadic minority community here> staying for weeks or months" (this would be redundant, as allemansretten has this restriction already)?  Something else?

Why not all of the above? No idea about this particular sign or Norwegian rules but why is that puzzling to you? I have seen similar rules (spending the night is allowed but you have to remove your tent during the day) elsewhere and a sign that reminds people of a general rule isn't particularly surprising either, be it for the benefit of visitors, to make sure people are aware of the rule, because someone complained people were abusing the rule, or to be able to point to it when enforcing the rule…

"the times refer to weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays/holidays, respectively" how do you know? I was wondering if it was just translated into different languages.

@FranckDernoncourt  Saturday hours in parens and Sunday/PH in red is a common convention in the Nordics, you often see this in parking signs etc.

It does not presumably refer to the twenty-first day of October.

@phoog I am not sure if your comment is in jest, but dates would never be written "mm-dd" in Norway, rather "dd/mm".

I bet it's "no camping for teenagers (and then some)", to avoid any related noise and mess from wild parties. To avoid trouble, the owners/authorities only want responsible grown adults and their young kids.

@ToivoSäwén it's partly in jest, partly in remembering that the format in Sweden is yyyy-mm-dd, following the ISO, though I would be very surprised if anyone from Sweden would denote a date without a year using two numbers in month-day order.

Where exactly did you find this sign? If it is posted in a parking lot, 'camping' most certainly refers to use of caravans and motorhomes and not tenting.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo In a parking lot alongside County Road 21 on the shore of Femsjøen, near Halden, Norway.

Are time spans normally written that way in Norway? As an American, I would have expected to see something more like "10:00 - 21:00", and guessed that "10-21" was a reference to a local ordinance number or something like that.

@lambshaanxy thanks, great to know, I had no idea it was a common convention. I posted What does "10-21 (10-21) 10-21" mean on a sign? in case comments get cleaned, you're welcome to post your comment there as an answer.

@DaveTweed: Yes, but "kl." might be added in front in order to make it clear that the numbers refer to times of day. A store sign might say simply "08–22(20)", meaning open from 8 to 22 on weekdays, 8 to 20 on Saturdays, and closed on Sundays and holidays.

If you found this sign in a parking lot, as clarified in the comments, I would (as a Norwegian) interpret the sign to only refer to camping with caravans and motorhomes and that it in a rather convoluting way is trying to say that it is not allowed to stay for more than one night with a vehicle. The Norwegian word 'camping' is not identical in meaning and coverage to the English word and in a Norwegian context usually only used to describe staying at a commercial camping site or living in a caravan (campingvogn) or a motorhome (campingbil or bobil). Staying in a tent outside a commercial camping site, would usually be referred to as 'telting' or in English 'tenting'. The English translation on the sign is simply sloppy and makes the impression that the restriction is much wider than actually ment.
As I already commented on lambshaanxy's answer, the freedom and right to roam is anchored in Norwegian law and the municipality or even a private land owner has very restricted legal possibilities to deny tenting on a property. Since Femsjøen is a source of drinking water, the municipality would in this case actually have the possibility to restrict access and conduct around the lake, but there does not seem to be any.
Staying in a caravan or motorhome is not covered by the freedom to roam, but may be restricted by municipal parking regulations. It is not uncommon that staying in a parking lot or at a rest stop is limited to one night.
Other municipalities manage to inform about such restrictions in a much clearer way than the sign you have found and posted in your question. The municipality of Nesodden uses signs like these, where for some reason only parts of the text is translated to English. The pictograms should perhaps already make it clear that the camping restriction only applies to caravans and motorhomes, but the Norwegian text makes it absolutely clear:

Tenting and other stays at the property are not allowed for more than
two days.



It means what it says on the tin: you're not allowed to have a tent camper set up there during daytime hours.
Why the sign is there goes into speculation, but I presume the intent is to effectively ban multi-day stays.
Update: The comments have clarified that the sign was in a parking lot, which means this is applies to car camping (caravan/motorhome) only. Which also explains why it's using the parking restriction style signage with parentheses for Saturday and red text for Sunday.

It's debatable whether putting up a tent during daytime hours even counts as camping (how about those half-open wind shelters fishing people sometimes use?), but the people setting up this sign probably think it does...

@gerrit I believe that not removing the tent after 10AM with intent to stay will be viewed as a clear violation.

Why does it say it thrice, though?

@JackAidley See lambaanxy's comment to the question: it's "weekdays // (Saturdays) // Sundays or PH"

Fairly certain the sign is illegal.

@Taemyr: why? many countries have similar rules (but not so explicit written): bivouac (night camping) permitted on most of land, but staying longer ("camping" can be done only one certain places).

@gerrit "It's debatable whether putting up a tent during daytime hours even counts as camping": any meaningful debate on that question would have to occur before a local judge, however, which most people will want to avoid even if they could be 100% certain of success -- especially tourist visitors from distant places.

@phoog Even more debatable: parking a camping car for a couple of hours (by far the most common type of roadside camping in Scandinavia is by camping car).

@GiacomoCatenazzi Because the freedom and right to roam is secured in Norwegian law and restrictions to that is only allowed in a limited number of situations. I am not sure where this sign is located, but if camping hat been prohibited because it e.g. is in a nature protection area, camping would have been completely banned and not just during the day time. It does not look like an official sign. Official signs use a different font.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo what if it's on private property?

@phoog All uncultivated land is covered under right to roam in Norway, regardless of ownership

Does the right to roam actually allow you to set up camp for a week on private uncultivated land?

@JonCuster Not necessarily for a week, but at least for two nights.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo - thanks, did not know the limits.

-1, the points about right to roam and the answer makes it sound like this answer is factually incorrect

Right to roam doesn't apply everywhere. Norway has paid parking, roads with stopping restrictions, etc, just like anywhere else. And there are restrictions close to residential buildings.

@GiacomoCatenazzi Right to roam laws in Norway allows for bivouacing for two nights in areas considered wilderness ("utmark").  Although a parking space is probably not covered so it's not really relevant.
